# Error when downloading and unpacking zip file from website Error: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I have a script that downloads zip files to a folder on my desktop and afterwards unpacks them to a another location locally. Most of the files work fine except for some. I have tried to find a solution by searching for the error but can't wrap my head around where or why the error occurs.

I am downloading the data from a country specific website. I have about five country website that are being iterated through to download and unpack the data. As mentioned the zip files for one of them end up being corrupt. If I download and unpack the data manually it works perfectly fine. So I assume it is a Python error?

The part `if Country != "BE"` is only a temp "solution" as the script otherwise "crashes".
First the data is being downloaded to `DataOut` location and then should be unpacked `UnpackedDataOut`:

```
with open(os.path.join(DataOut,file_name),"wb") as file:
    response = get(domain + url)
    file.write(response.content) 

if Country != "BE":
    with ZipFile(DataOut+"\\"+file_name,"r") as zipObj:
        zipObj.extractall(UnpackedDataOut)
```

The data for BE was downloaded and if I try to open it manually after downloading it via Python it returns the message error in packed file.

Comment: It looks like `response.content` doesn't contain what you think it does. Get your code to do a bit of checking on `response`, instead of just assuming that the `get()` call is behaving as you expect.

Comment: If the zip files downloaded from a specific url are having the issue, then try to manually download one of them from your browser and check if that is in fact in proper zip file format - i.e it opens fine in a normal zip utility.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this snipet to download and extract zip file:

```
import urllib
import zipfile

url = "http://www.gutenberg.lib.md.us/4/8/8/2/48824/48824-8.zip"
extract_dir = "example"

zip_path, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "r") as f:
    f.extractall(extract_dir)
```